# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' after using 'pip install numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I tried installing numpy using the command `'pip install numpy'` and ran `'import numpy'` but I received the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` when I tried to re-run the code. After reading similar questions on SO, I ran `pip3 install numpy`, but since i already installed it, I received the message `Requirement already satisfied`.

*NOTE:* I have read other similar questions on SO, but none of them solve my problem.

---

***Possible solution for future readers:***

Like @Sampath mentioned in his answer, I had two versions of python installed. To solve the issue, I manually deleted all the installation files of the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

1. It is likely that there are 2 python versions(Python2.X and Python3.X) are installed in your system.
2. `pip` is likely pointing to your Python2.X and so if you want to used libraries installed in this version ===> use `python` to run
3. `pip3` is pointing to your Python3.X, so use `Python3` in your terminal to use this.

Note:

- To know installed libraries in your python2 use `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze` for Python3
- In case, if you are getting error for Python3 as not then this is like to be system path issues.

If you are still having trouble, you learn more about `Anaconda-Python` which has a curated list of steps and guidelines that are easy for beginners too. Hope this helps!

Comment: you're right, it seems as though there are two versions installed on my system. If I run a python file that uses NumPy on the command prompt with either 'python' or 'python3', the code executes perfectly without any errors. However, when i try running this same code on the IDLE, I receive a module error. Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Comment: @Newbie123 - Glad to know! About IDEL, sorry I have no answer here. Recommendation - I use  `Pycharm Community Edition IDE` to configure the python path to my project. So I now suggest using an IDE instead of IDLE, as they offer more features like TypeHinting, PEP8 checks, typo-errors, documentation,..etc.